# Are AWS token authorizers sufficient for tiered permissions based Lambda routes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

I know that a token authorizer is a custom AWS Lambda function that serves as a gateway or pre-processing step for AWS Lambda requests. It contains the token type, methodArn identifier and the token itself, which is placed in the header of a request to a Lambda route, and validated with something like this:

```
resp = tokens_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("token").eq(token))
```

I'm having a problem with our current authorizer. I need to have 3 levels of roles - regular, admin, and superuser and they can each only access specific resources/routes or methods. If this is my sole authorization mechanism for routes, how would a bearer token be sufficient to ALLOW or DENY specific requests, since a token authorizer generally just checks the database for the existence of the token?

Would I have to write extra logic in the authorizer function that takes into account what level of permissions the route requires? Would this require instead using a **request authorizer** that validates several fields and calculates the ALLOW or DENY response? Also, would a better design strategy to be to write 3 separate token authorizers for each level of user?

Answer (score 0):

For your case I would go with JWT token for custom authorizer. You can send any data within the token (in your case user role). And allow or deny access to endpoint based on that role.